# Rails - strong params removing empty fields from nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been working on this line of code for three days.
I have the following strong params:

```
def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(:country, {:ads_attributes => [:remote, :days]})
end
```

The method *param_clean* will delete from the *location_params* the empty fields, but it will not work with the nested **:ads_attributes**.
The main reason is that **param_clean** can only be called on **location_params** that has class **ActiveController::Parameters**. I can not call on **v** the method **param_clean**

```
def param_clean
    location_params.delete_if{  |k, v| v.empty? or v.instance_of?(ActionController::Parameters) && v.param_clean.empty? }
end
```

I receive the following error

```
undefined method `param_clean' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f..>
```

This is the value of location_params

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"country"=>"", "ads_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"remote"=>"0", "days"=>""} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

This is the value of `v` variable when the error is triggered

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"remote"=>"0", "days"=>""} permitted: true>

v.class => ActionController::Parameters
```

The method does not work with the nested parameters.
Thanks a lot for your help

Best Regards
Fabrizio

Comment: Did my solution work out for you?

Comment: I have to test, I just woke up. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `param_clean` method is not defined in `ActionController::Parameters` class. So, you have to change your approach, by either:

- Extending `ActionController::Parameters` to include the method (not that I would recommend it).
- Refactor the method. One way to do it would be as follows:

  ```
  def param_clean(_params)
    _params.delete_if do |k, v|
      if v.instance_of?(ActionController::Parameters)
        param_clean(v)
      end
      v.empty?
    end
  end

  # how to use it
  param_clean(location_params)
  ```

Comment: Hello Aegis. Your answer is the reason why this community is so **great**. I just have been on this for 3 days and I would never solve this alone. Thanks a lot. Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: Glad it help you

Comment: 2021 - and this worked for me. Thank you @aegis